# (1.9) Minecraft texture exception

Tags: java, json, minecraft

I'm a modding beginner and all my textures are pink-black.
I wonder what I'm doing wrong.
When I run my minecraft mod i always got this error:

```
Exception loading model for variant spmmod:sulfur_ore_nether#inventory for item spmmod:sulfur_ore_nether
java.lang.Exception: Could not load item model either from the normal location spmmod:item/sulfur_ore_nether or from the blockstate
```

spmmod.java:

```
package com.spmmod;
import com.spmmod.blocks.CustomBlock;
com.spmmod.items.CustomItem;
import com.spmmod.lib.ProxyCommon;
import com.spmmod.lib.References;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.init.Items;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.SidedProxy;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
@Mod(modid = References.MODID, name=References.NAME, version = References.Version)
public class spmmod
{
    @SidedProxy(clientSide = References.ProxyClient, serverSide = References.ProxyCommon)
    public static ProxyCommon proxy;

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("WILL REGISTER RENDERS");
        proxy.RegisterRenders();
        System.out.println("DID REGISTER RENDERS");
    }

    //Blocks

    public static CustomBlock sulfur_ore_nether;



    public spmmod()
    {
        this.sulfur_ore_nether = new CustomBlock(Material.rock, "sulfur_ore_nether", 0.4F, 0.5F, CustomBlock.HarvestToolEnum.PICKAXE, CustomBlock.HarvestLevelEnum.WOOD, CreativeTabs.tabBlock, 1, 6, 100, 10, 0, 300, new Block[]{Blocks.netherrack}, new Block[]{Blocks.lava}, 1, false, true, false);
    }
}
```

}

ProxyClient.java:

```
package com.spmmod.lib;

import com.spmmod.spmmod;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;

public class ProxyClient extends ProxyCommon
{
    @Override
    public void RegisterRenders()
    {
        spmmod.sulfur_ore_nether.RegisterRender("sulfur_ore_nether");
    }
}
```

models/block/sulfur_ore_nether.json:

```
{
    "parent": "block/cube_all",
    "textures": {
        "all": "spmmod:blocks/sulfur_ore_nether"
    }
}
```

models/item/sulfur_ore_nether.json:

```
{
    "parent": "spmmod:block/sulfur_ore_nether",
    "display": {
        "thirdperson": {
            "rotation": [ 10, -45, 170 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 1.5, -2.75 ],
            "scale": [ 0.375, 0.375, 0.375 ]
        }
    }
}
```

blockstates/sulfur_ore_nether:

```
{
    "variants": {
        "normal": { "model": "spmmod:sulfur_ore_nether" }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but maybe `spmmod.sulfur_ore_nether.RegisterRender("sulfur_ore_nether");` should be `spmmod.sulfur_ore_nether.RegisterRender("spmmod:sulfur_ore_nether");`?

Comment: In sulfur_ore_nether.java, in function RegisterRender(String name): `Minecraft.getMinecraft().getRenderItem().getItemModelMesher().register(Item.getItemFromBlock(this), 0, new ModelResourceLocation("spmmod:"+name, "inventory"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did wrong was that I edited the JSON files in TextEdit with the setting "smart quotes" on. The smart quote isn't the same as the normal quote. When I turned off smart quotes everything worked fine.